# NSOpenPanel custom sound

Tags: swift, macos

Is there a way to change the sound that plays when an NSOpenPanel is opened?

I've googled my fingers to the bone and can't find anything, maybe it's not possible.

Comment: The what now? There's no sound for me when I open an open panel. Are you maybe using an Accessibility feature? In any case, specify version of macOS.

Comment: You're absolutely right @KenThomases. There is no sound, I created a new test project and I didn't get any sound. As I looked through the project closer I realized that there is an NSButton sound property that can be set in interface builder, that's what was causing the sound :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

NSOpenPanel does not have a way to set a sound property when opening a panel. NSButtons properties can be used for that.

In the screenshot, you can see how you can set a custom sound to the button.